# Converting a tuple to a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
import re
from collections import Counter

words = re.findall('\w+', open('/Users/Jack/Desktop/testytext').read().lower())

listy = Counter(words).most_common()


theNewList = list(listy)


theNewList[1][1] = 10

#****ERROR HERE****
#Traceback (most recent call last):
# File "countTheWords.py", line 16, in <module>
#    theNewList[1][1] = 10
#TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

In my mind the list() call should convert 'listy' to a list. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And the value of 'listy' is what exactly? Should we guess it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.most_common()` returns a list of tuples. When you do `list(listy)`, you're actually changing nothing. It will not change the tuples inside to lists.

As tuples are immutable, they won't let you change items in it (compared to lists which are mutable).

You can change them to lists, however, by using `map()`:

```
map(list, listy)
```

Answer (score 2):

`listy` *is* a `list`:

```
>>> type(listy)
<type 'list'>
```

Its elements are not:

```
>>> type(listy[1])
<type 'tuple'>
```

And you're trying to modify one of their elements:

```
>>> type(listy[1][1])
<type 'int'>
```

You can convert the elements like so:

```
>>> listier = [list(e) for e in listy]
>>> type(listier)
<type 'list'>
>>> type(listier[1])
<type 'list'>
>>> type(listier[1][1])
<type 'int'>
```

And then assign:

```
>>> listier[1][1] = 10
>>> listier[1][1]
10
```

Comment: where's `listiest`?  :)

Comment: @roippi: I'm reserving that for when `type(listier[1][1]) == list`!

Answer (score 0):

`theNewList[1]` is a valid list item-access, which returns a tuple. Thus `theNewList[1][1] = 10` is an attempt to assign to a tuple item. That's invalid, as tuples are immutable.

Why would you want to assign a new count anyway?